# Clean solution for building one WAR archive from multiple gradle sub-projects

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, war

With Gradle it is possible to build a .war archive from a Java project. I've always been using a project setup as follows to pack some JavaScript SPA (Angular, vue.js...) frontend and a Spring Boot backend together into one .war file:

**Directory structure**

```
/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  /server
     /build/libs/server.war 
     /src ...
     build.gradle
  /client
     /dist/**                     <== This is where e.g. webpack puts the SPA build
     build.gradle
     /src ...
```

**Topmost settings.gradle**

```
include 'client', 'server'
```

**'server' build.gradle**

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'idea'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.1.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.5.RELEASE'
  id 'war'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
 compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16')
 annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
 runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

war.dependsOn(':client:build')
war {
  from '../client/dist/'
}
```

**'client' build.gradle**

```
plugins {
  id 'com.nickcharles.yarn-run' version '1.0.1'
}
```

This is working just fine. But I can't imagine that this is the cleanest solution for that kind of task.

Backdraws of my solution are:

- Final result of build is stored in `build/libs` of the `:server` subproject, not in the root project where it semantically belongs
- The built client must be refered to in a static way.

How would a clean solution/the contents of the topmost build.gradle file look like, in order to avoid those backdraws?